# Use strict отличия при использование кода

Tags: javascript

Привет...
Какие отличия есть при использовании use strict ?

Одним с них ,который удалось найти

**Пример 1:**

```
function isStrictMode(){
    return !this;
} 
//returns false, since 'this' refers to global object and '!this' becomes false

function isStrictMode(){   
    "use strict";
    return !this;
}

alert(isStrictMode());
```

**Пример 2:**

```
"use strict";

function test() {  
      foo = "bar"; //ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable foo
}
```

Можно посмотреть другие полезные примеры ,которые покажут разницу ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На MDN есть неплохая подборка примеров: [MDN: Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)